# Javascript onclick function element selector

Tags: javascript, onclick

I need to run onclick function when **`<a href..></a>`** is clicked.

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div id="btn">
        <a href="#" id="btnRight" class="right"></a>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var element = document.querySelectorAll("a#btnRight.right");   
element.onclick = (function() {

    var count = 0;

    return function(e) {

        count++;
        console.log(count);
        if (count === 3) {

            //...

            count = 0;
        }
    };
})();
</script>
```

I can't use `<a href="#" onclick=""...></a>` in html so I need to select **a#btnRight.right**. I tried:

- `var element = document.querySelectorAll("a#btnRight.right");`
- `var element = document.querySelector("#btnRight.right");`
- `var element = document.getElementById("btnRight").getElementsByClassName("right")[0];`
- `var element = document.getElementById("btnRight").getElementsByTagName("a");`

But it doesn't work. Thank you

Comment: `querySelectorAll` will return a `NodeList`. Try `querySelector` instead. Also when you already have id why are you complicating selector? Just use `document.querySelector("@btnRight")`

Comment: Change to using `document.getElementById('btnRight')`, you don't need anything else, as an ID is always unique.

Comment: @evolutionxbox If your version works, then the posted version `var element = document.querySelector("#btnRight.right");` should also work

Comment: http://jsbin.com/hejocar/1/edit?html,console,output — One of the versions you said doesn't work **does**.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div id="btn">
        <a href="#" id="btnRight" class="right">CLICK ME!</a>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var element = document.getElementById("btnRight");
    element.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var count = 0;
        return function(e) {
            count++;
            console.log(count);
            if (count === 3) {
                //...
                count = 0;
            }
        };
    }()
    )
</script>
```

Comment: What is the difference between `element.onclick` and `element.addEventListener(..)`?

Comment: @Hanz
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)

BTW: your var element = document.getElementById("btnRight")
returns array of elements, not element. And element.onclick = (function() {...})() runs when the document is loaded. you should not call this func, it will be called when element is clicked =)

Answer (score 0):

querySelectorAll returns a nodeList with all of the element with the specified id , so you need to change element to element[0] in case you have only one element with that id , and change your element id to btnRight like that :

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div id="btn">
        <a href="#" id="btnRight" class="right"></a>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var element = document.querySelectorAll("#btnRight");   
element[0].onclick = (function() {

    var count = 0;

    return function(e) {

        count++;
        console.log(count);
        if (count === 3) {

            //...

            count = 0;
        }
    };
})();
</script>
```

of course you can also use getElementById like that :

```
var element = document.getElementById("btnRight");   
element.onclick =  (function() {

    var count = 0;

    return function(e) {

        count++;
        console.log(count);
        if (count === 3) {

            //...

            count = 0;
        }
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

little modification to your code:

```
<div class="gallery">
<div id="btn">
    <a href="#" id="btnRight" class="right">pp</a>
</div>
```

```
   document.getElementById("btnRight").onclick = CustomFunction;

   function CustomFunction() {

    var count = 0;

    return function (e) {

        count++;
        console.log(count);
        if (count === 3) {

            //...

            count = 0;

        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try below selector, you can select any DOM element using its ID and make sure ID should be unique in your DOM.

```
 element = document.getElementById('btnRight');
```

Also, If you are trying to select multiple elements having your 'right' class then you should use below selector.

```
 element = document.getElementsByClassName("right");
```

Comment: Please add explanation. You are answering for reader and not for OP

Comment: When I tried this selector, typo was a problem. Thanks